# How to correctly update more than 1 data in database

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to make a simple function that will charge cashback for purchases on the site. The principle is as follows: I have a `buy` table, where all purchase operations are indicated, and in this table there are 3 required columns: `user_id`, `bank` and `status`. Bank - transaction amount, status - transaction status, user_id - ID at `users` table. If status is `2`, then the purchase has been paid. I take all the data from the `buy` table, get it with status = 2, and then I need to enter to the `users` table, find the user ID there by `user_id` from the `buy` table, see the amount of his purchase where status is 2, and if everything is fine, I need to add 1 % cashback of the purchase amount.

I'm trying to do it all with this function:

```
public function cashbackUser()
{
    $find_user = DB::table('buy')->where('status', 2)->get();
    $users = DB::table('users')->get();
    foreach ($users as $addCashback) {
        $addCashback->cashback = $addCashback->cashback + $find_user->bank / 100 * 1;
        $addCashback->save();
    }
}
```

But i received error: `Property [bank] does not exist on this collection instance.`. How i understand, it can't find the all summs from `bank` at `buy` table, because i can't to use `->get()`? What i need to change and get work it?

Comment: `$find_user` is a collection. If you only need one element, use `first()` instead of `get()`. If you expect more than one, you'll have to loop over it like you do with `$users`, and determine, based on your business logic, how to join up `$find_user` and `$users`.

Comment: yes, i need to all elements

Comment: Do you want to add 1% of all the purchases combined ?

Comment: yes, to all sucess puchased with `status = 2`

Comment: Post another question so I can provide solution, this question is already closed.

Comment: can post only once in 90 minutes :( maybe you can write solution for example in pastebin.com?

Comment: `public function cashbackUser()
{
    $users = DB::table('users')->get();
    foreach ($users as $addCashback) {
        //assuming the primary key in users table is id
        $total_purchase = DB::table('buy')->where('user_id', $addCashback['id'])->where('status', 2)->sum('bank');
        //one percent of total purchase is calculated like (1/100)*total_purchase
        $addCashback->cashback = $addCashback->cashback + ((1/100)*$total_purchase);
        $addCashback->save();
    }
}`

Comment: just copy past this into your editor and try it

Comment: received: `Cannot use object of type stdClass as array`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226058/discussion-between-omar-abbas-and-yrbet).